# How I can start a build using Rest API

Tags: rest, openshift

I want start app's build using Openshift Rest API https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/index.html.
What I need:

change source ref (branch) for build

start new build from new branch

without using triggers build or oc tool.

I cann't find how to do that in https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/apis-build.openshift.io/v1.Build.html

It can be done using OC Tool Analogue:
`oc start-build name -n namespase`
But I want do this using REST API
Thank you very much!

Comment: Run ``oc start-build`` with the ``--loglevel 9`` option and it will show you what REST API calls it is making. You should be able to work it out from that.

Comment: Thank you. I found it https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/apis-build.openshift.io/v1.BuildConfig.html#Post-apis-build.openshift.io-v1-namespaces-namespace-buildconfigs-name-instantiate

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xxx" -H 'Accept: application/json' -XPOST "$openshiftUrl/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/YOURNAMESPACE/buildconfigs/CONFIGNAME/instantiatebinary?name=XXXX&namespace=YOURNAMESSPACE" --data-binary @/tmp/eQXEUXr.zip
```

using axios

```
return axios({
   method: 'post',
   url: 'url/apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/YYY/buildconfigs/XXX/instantiatebinary?name=XXX&namespace=YYY',
   data: fs.createReadStream('/tmp/eQXEUXr.zip'),
   headers: {
    'content-type': `application/octet-stream`,
    'Authorization': 'Bearer aaaaaa',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
},
   maxContentLength: Infinity,
   maxBodyLength: Infinity,
   httpsAgent: new Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false
   }),
   timeout: 300000,
```

}